# function inside Controller inAngularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have two functions drag_drop and drag_start , inside these functions I nedd some data from a controller scope. 
My code is somthing like that

```
function drag_start(event) {
  event.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "move";
  event.dataTransfer.setData("text", event.target.getAttribute('id'));
}

function drag_drop(event) {
  // here I want to use  $scope from a controller        
}
```

controller code :

```
        institutionController.controller('institutionController',function     
            $http.get('/myResponses').then(function(myres) {
            $scope.myRps=myres.data;
            // I want to use $scope.myRps when I  drag and drop an element inside a div
```

HTML code :

```
          ul(ng-hide="siwtchCI",class="list-inline")
              li(ng-repeat="ownInst in ownInsts",draggable='true',ondragstart='drag_start(event)')
                  a(class="btn btn-default btn-org" ,role="button") {{ownInst.org.name}}


              #drop_zone(ondrop='drag_drop(event)', ondragover='return false')
```

the problem is when I put my two  functions inside the controller my  html elements are not draggable anymore

Comment: Please post more information. What are you trying to access in your controller? Where is all the relevant controller code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try declaring the functions drag_start and drag_stop in scope.
Also on html you need to specify something as below
ondragstart="angular.element(document.getElementById('xyz')).scope().drag(event)"
This would surely call the drag method you have defined in the controller
where xyz represents id of the html element to be dragged.

Comment: it works but  my 'xyz' is  a scope variable  so when I do this in my HTML : ondragstart='angular.element(document.getElementById({{ownInst.org._id}})).scope().drag_start(event)' , javascript didn't recognize    ownInst.org._id

Comment: Give the id to your HTML LI element as below                                                  li (id = "xyz" ng-repeat="ownInst in ownInsts",draggable='true',ondragstart='document.getElementById('xyz')).scope‌​().drag_start(event)), let me know if it works for you

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you used 'ng' directives on the HTML side, that's why regular functions don't work. Please be a habit that if you are going to create a function inside a controller, might as well put a scope into it.

```
$scope.drag_start = function(event){

}

$scope.drag_drop = function(event){

}
```

This should do the trick

Comment: Still not working, maybe because  I'm using The ondragstart attribute of HTML5,

Comment: @YoussefKorchi, I'm not really familiar with the drag and drop of HTML5 but I saw a native AngularJS for you. https://github.com/logicbomb/lvlDragDrop and its demo - http://logicbomb.github.io/ng-directives/drag-drop.html

Comment: Thank you Dean Christian , I will try that in case html5 method won't work